# Texture fail to render - DirectX 9

Tags: c++, directx

I have this code in DirectX 9, in which I need to get the DC from a COM interface and draw it. I do get the DC and it contains the image, but I get a black screen. Any ideas why?

```
    LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 pRenderSurface = NULL, pRenderSurfaceTMP = NULL;

    m_pRenderTexture->GetSurfaceLevel(0, &pRenderSurface);
    if (pRenderSurface == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    m_pD3DDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(m_nWidth, m_nHeight,
        D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &pRenderSurfaceTMP, 0);

    m_pD3DDevice->GetRenderTargetData(pRenderSurface,pRenderSurfaceTMP);

    HDC hDC = NULL;
    hr = pRenderSurfaceTMP->GetDC(&hDC);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        return FALSE;   

    if (m_pViewObject != NULL)
    {
        // RECT is relative to the windowless container rect
        RECTL rcRect = {0, 0, m_nWidth, m_nHeight};  

        // Draw onto the DC!
        hr = m_pViewObject->Draw(DVASPECT_CONTENT, 1,
            NULL, NULL, NULL, hDC, &rcRect, NULL, NULL,
            0);
    }


    pRenderSurface->ReleaseDC(hDC);
    pRenderSurface->Release();


    // Draw the surface
    m_pD3DDevice->SetStreamSource( 0, m_pVertexBuffer, 0, sizeof(Vertex) );
    m_pD3DDevice->SetTexture( 0, m_pRenderTexture );


    hr = m_pD3DDevice->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP, 0, 2);

    m_hbrBackground = NULL;
    pRenderSurfaceTMP->Release();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use fixed pipeline? If so, you should set texture states using `SetTextureStageState`. Does `m_pVertexBuffer` have an appropriate FVF format and correct texture coordinates? You should also debug your application and check if it fails on `if (FAILED(hr)) return false;` - `GetDC` could fail if you don't meet the requirements (see remarks section - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205894(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Well, the thing is I have this code working in a seperate app, and I tried adapting it into another app. So the FVF format and texture coordinates are correct, I think (I can see a texture drawn where I wanted, but it is black). I also know that the GetDC does not fail since I printed it into a bitmap and saw the correct image. I think my app is using a fixed pipeline (I'm pretty new to DX), and I tried using SetTextureStageState. It didnt seems to change anything. Any other ideas? I also see that GetRenderTargetData fails, but I am able to get the DC from pRenderSurfaceTMP. I'm confused.

Comment: You can get the DC from pRenderSurfaceTMP but it points to an empty surface, because of GetRenderTargetData failure.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `m_pRenderTexture` is created with `D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET`. The size and format of both `pRenderSurface` and `pRenderSurfaceTMP` should match. For more info, see when `GetRenderTargetData` fails: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174405(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks - now I get no error. BUT, I still get a black rectangle instead of the real image (reminder, the dc contains the correct image for sure). What am I still missing?

Comment: Since you call `m_pD3DDevice->SetTexture( 0, m_pRenderTexture );` I assume that you want to draw an object (full-screen quad?) textured with `m_pRenderTexture`. However, you draw `m_pViewObject` onto `pRenderSurfaceTMP` which is a copy of the `m_pRenderTexture`'s surface. Because of that, nothing is being drawn on the `m_pRenderTexture`'s surface itself.

Comment: OK, I kinda suspected this is the problem. but how do I update m_pRenderTexture? I tried UpdateSurface, it didn't change anything. How do I solve this?

Comment: Why don't you just `GetDC` from the `pRenderSurface` instead of creating a temporary surface?

Comment: By the way, do you render a full-screen quad here: `m_pD3DDevice->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP, 0, 2);` ? If so, wouldn't be easier to get DC from the back buffer and render `m_pViewObject` directly onto the screen?

Comment: GetDC from pRenderSurface failed, something to do with the format  (picked that up in post I found). It's not a full screen, but I can try whatever you are suggesting. Can you please tell me exactly what to try? (As you probably feagured out, I'm new at this).

Comment: If `GetDC` fails, see remarks section - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205894(v=vs.85).aspx Reading documentation is really helpful when debugging Direct3D apps. If you couldn't solve the problem yourself, I need to know how you create `m_pRenderTexture` - could you paste some more code?

Comment: Of course I tried the documentation. This is how I create my texture: D3DXCreateTexture (m_pD3DDevice, m_nWidth, m_nHeight, 1, D3DUSAGE_RENDERTARGET, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &m_pRenderTexture);
I also tried: 
m_pD3DDevice->CreateTexture(m_nWidth,m_nHeight,1,0,D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8,D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM,&m_pRenderTexture,NULL);
 and I was able to get the DC, but still got a black rectangle.

Comment: One more thing I have to add - I really do not have, at the moment, any preferred way of doing it - I just want to know how to get it done.  And hey, thanks for your assistance and patience.

Comment: If you create a texture in D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, it's inaccessible for Direct3D device and you can't draw it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
m_pD3DDevice->CreateTexture(m_nWidth, m_nHeight, 1, 0, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8,
                            D3DPOOL_MANAGED, &m_pRenderTexture, NULL);

// ...

LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 pRenderSurface = NULL;
if (FAILED(m_pRenderTexture->GetSurfaceLevel(0, &pRenderSurface))) return FALSE;

HDC hDC = NULL;
if (FAILED(pRenderSurface->GetDC(&hDC))) return FALSE;   

if (m_pViewObject != NULL)
{
    RECTL rcRect = {0, 0, m_nWidth, m_nHeight};

    m_pViewObject->Draw(DVASPECT_CONTENT, 1,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, hDC, &rcRect, NULL, NULL, 0);
}

pRenderSurface->ReleaseDC(hDC);
pRenderSurface->Release();

m_pD3DDevice->SetStreamSource( 0, m_pVertexBuffer, 0, sizeof(Vertex) );
m_pD3DDevice->SetTexture( 0, m_pRenderTexture );

m_pD3DDevice->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP, 0, 2);
```

or this:

```
m_pD3DDevice->CreateTexture(m_nWidth, m_nHeight, 1, 0, D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8,
                            D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, &m_pRenderTexture, NULL);

// ...

LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 pRenderSurfaceTMP = NULL;
m_pD3DDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(m_nWidth, m_nHeight,
    D3DFMT_X8R8G8B8, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, &pRenderSurfaceTMP, 0);

HDC hDC = NULL;
if (FAILED(pRenderSurfaceTMP->GetDC(&hDC))) return FALSE;   

if (m_pViewObject != NULL)
{
    RECTL rcRect = {0, 0, m_nWidth, m_nHeight};

    m_pViewObject->Draw(DVASPECT_CONTENT, 1,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, hDC, &rcRect, NULL, NULL, 0);
}

pRenderSurfaceTMP->ReleaseDC(hDC);

LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 pRenderSurface = NULL;
if (FAILED(m_pRenderTexture->GetSurfaceLevel(0, &pRenderSurface)))
    return FALSE;

if (FAILED(m_pD3DDevice->UpdateSurface(pRenderSurfaceTMP, NULL,
                                       pRenderSurface, NULL))) return FALSE;

pRenderSurface->Release();

m_pD3DDevice->SetStreamSource( 0, m_pVertexBuffer, 0, sizeof(Vertex) );
m_pD3DDevice->SetTexture( 0, m_pRenderTexture );

m_pD3DDevice->DrawPrimitive(D3DPT_TRIANGLESTRIP, 0, 2);
```

Comment: I already tried it. The problem is that CreateTexture with D3DPOOL_MANAGED fails (D3DERR_INVALIDCALL). I dont know why, but in the entire application they have not used D3DPOOL_MANAGED, only D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM.

Comment: Well, I tried option #2. Nothing fails, but I only get a grey rectangle... any other ideas?

Comment: You said previously you got a black rectangle. Now it's grey. I think it's working now, because it's drawing something. Make sure `m_pViewObject->Draw` is drawing correctly (what is it supposed to be drawing?).

Comment: Well, not exactly. In the code I had before I started all the other attempts, I had a FillRect that caused the black collor. I know for a fact that the drawing on the DC works. I did a BitBlt with the dc I draw to to the screen dc, and I can see the image being drawn.

Comment: Moreover - your code is perfectly fine. If I use it in another temporary project, it works fine. But in my app (which is a fully functioning directx app), this simply does not work. Something is different, and I have no idea why. What can be the cause of such symptoms?

Comment: Hard to say, make sure you don't have any locked resources while you're calling this code. If this normally works, you should have a bug somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Well, I got it to work - but not using this code. The way it is done is creating a texture with D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, another one with D3DPOOL_DEFAULT, and after I draw to the DC I copy the bits to a locked rect I got from the sys texture. Then I update the video texture from the sys texture.
I was able to find this code somewhereelse in my app code, but I admit I do not understand why it is done this way and why what you suggested did not work... If you have any insights, I would be glad to hear them. Anyway - thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know, the code I've posted should work and it's strange it doesn't in your app only. Anyway, I'm glad you've finally got it working.